# How to write the following as an eager loaded query in Rails 4.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eager-loading

So I am using the geocoder gem in Rails 4.1 and have the following models setup.  The code works but the Bullet gem is detecting this line *places.select { |place| @countries.places.include?(place.country) }* as an N+1 query.  Is there a good rails-ish way to write it via eager loading? The trick is that I want to return a set of countries that only contain the places returned by the Geocoder method *near*.

**Model setup**

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :places
end

class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :country
end
```

**In some_controller.rb**

```
@countries = Country.all
places = Place.near(some_latitude_longitude_coordinates, 5500)
places.select { |place| @countries.places.include?(place.country) }
```

EDIT:  one correction for some_controller.rb - It should read:

```
places.select { |place| @countries.include?(place.country) }
```

As noted in the comments below, Country.all is really just a placeholder to make it easier to read the code.  In actuality, @countries is really another subset of countries (as opposed to Country.all) with some property such as "all communist countries".  Thus, I want to find the intersection of the countries of places near a certain set of coordinates and countries with some property such as "all communist countries".

Comment: `@countries.places.include?(place.country)` what does this do?

Comment: Hi Tamer, that was a typo - I made the edit above, basically it is an intersection between the set of all countries and the countries of the places that have been found near some coordinates.  @countries is really another subset of countries (as opposed to Country.all) with some property such as "all communist countries"

Comment: checkout my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it but it should work:

```
@countries = Country.all
places = Place.includes(:country).near(some_latitude_longitude_coordinates, 5500)
places.select { |place| @countries.include?(place.country) }
```

This will get you **places** whose countries are included in the `@countries` collection.

Answer (score 0):

To proper eager load your records, you need to make one query. I would suggest the following:

```
@places = Place.near(some_latitude_longitude_coordinates, 5500).joins(:country).where(country_id: @countries.map(&:id))
```